# Gitlab - how to delete utility commit messages?

Tags: git, gitlab

In our gitlab commit messages we use some standard strings to trigger our builds and other analysis.

After some time obviously our git history will become full of these useless messages.
Is there any way to make some cleanup of our git histories?

Comment: The message and the commit is one thing, so you can't just remove the message. There are several possible approaches to do what you want to do, but we'll need much more information.

Comment: Another thing that jumps out at me is *some standard strings to trigger our builds*, why? This seems wrong, typically you'd achieve this by only building a master branch that you only merge into when you want a build to be triggered. I'd say this is your real issue

Comment: You will have to rewrite history, and this is more painful than it sounds if you're multiple people working together. The reason why this is not a solved problem or something made easy is that you've selected a very bad workflow. You should have a branch that you build, and only merge into this branch when you're done with your feature branches. Then you would simply react to new commits appearing on this branch, regardless of these standardized messages. This is typically the role of the `master` branch, though you can select a different one/name if you want.

Comment: But to answer your question, yes there is a way to clean up the history. You could use `git filter-branch` and ommit the commits you no longer want, but you must make sure to synchronize **everyones** local repositories or you're just a push away from getting them back. It will involve a lot of work, each time you want to clean up, and likely every member of your team would have to ditch their local repositories afterwards and reclone to make sure nobody has the old structure, again, **every time**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do those commits on a Personal/environment/feature branch, you just need to do a [SQUASH COMMIT](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/squash_and_merge.html) when merging to a common branch like for example `master` is.

> Squashing lets you tidy up the commit history of a branch when
>   accepting a merge request. It applies all of the changes in the merge
>   request as a single commit, and then merges that commit using the
>   merge method set for the project.

So, every merge you do on a new branch in the Squash way, will be completely clean.

**EDIT FOR RECCOMENDATION:**

> I strongly reccomend to you to follow good practices
>   when creating your branches and project different versions. This is
>   called the [Gitlab flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/gitlab_flow.html). This will help you avoiding crazy "commit deletes" and will allow you to clarify your development procedure.

If you see this URL, the trick of mapping, for example, branches with environments or features, helps doing things much more clearer. Also, when you commit to a "higher level" branch, you squash commit and clean the original branch, as It's unneded.*(If you are following a good DevOps path, if your branch is being merged, it should be fully tested and functional. That's what you are looking for with gitlab-ci).*

Also, I've found [this part of the document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/gitlab_flow.html#squashing-commits-with-rebase) that goes deeper explaining how Squash commits work on Gitlab flow.